# Scalar function too slow - Calculated field in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

I have a big query, (really big, 800+columns - can't really make it smaller)
that I'm trying to build in the most efficient way.

I have some fields like this:

```
SELECT distinct(td.EVENT_ID), 
       td.MENU_HINT, 
       td.EVENT_NAME, 
       td.EVENT_DT AS Expr1003, 
       COUNT(td.EVENT_NAME) AS [Total Runners], 
       -- AS [WinnerPrice], 
       -- COUNT(td.ID) AS [WinnerCount],
       SUM(CASE WHEN td.BSP >= 1 AND td.BSP < 2 THEN td.BSP END) AS Sum1to2, 
       count(CASE WHEN td.BSP >= 1 AND td.BSP < 2 THEN td.BSP END) AS count1to2, 
       avg(CASE WHEN td.BSP >= 1 AND td.BSP < 2 THEN td.BSP END) AS average1to2,
       dbo.FN_SumWinnerRunners(td.EVENT_ID,34,55,0,7,12) AS [TEST FUNCTION],
       SUM(CASE WHEN (td.BSP >= 2 AND td.BSP < 3) AND td.WIN_LOSE =1 THEN td.BSP END) AS SumWinnerPrice2to3, 
       count(CASE WHEN (td.BSP >= 2 AND td.BSP < 3) AND td.WIN_LOSE =1 THEN td.BSP END) AS CountWinnerPrice2to3
       FROM tblData td 
GROUP BY td.EVENT_ID, 
         td.MENU_HINT, 
         td.EVENT_NAME, 
         td.EVENT_DT
ORDER BY [Total Runners] DESC;
```

And here a graphical one (click to enlarge):
[image]

if you notice, I've tried, as I have several queries that are fairly similar, to use a function (dbo.FN_SumWinnerRunners(td.EVENT_ID,34,55,0,7,12)

the definition for it below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_SumWinnerRunners](
                                @event_id    INT,   
                                @BSPFrom     SMALLINT, 
                                @BSPTo       SMALLINT, 
                                @Win_Lose    SMALLINT, 
                                @RunnersFrom SMALLINT, 
                                @RunnersTo   SMALLINT)
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
     BEGIN
         DECLARE @result FLOAT=
         (
             SELECT SUM(CASE
                            WHEN(td.BSP >= @BSPFrom
                                 AND td.BSP < @BSPTo)
                                AND td.WIN_LOSE = @Win_Lose
                            THEN td.BSP
                        END)
             FROM tblData td
             WHERE td.EVENT_ID = @event_id
             HAVING COUNT(td.EVENT_NAME) > 6
                    AND COUNT(td.EVENT_NAME) <= 11
         );
         RETURN @result;
     END;
GO
```

the thing is that apparently the function is killing my performance, the column that uses the function take the query from less than a second, to 3 minutes.
but at the same time I can't figure out how to do it without one, as I need to do a sum from event_name only in cases in which the count of event name fulfills the query.

so my question would be what am I breaking from the function that is making it super slow

and here some execution plans: the one from above is without the function, the one below with the function (click to enlarge):

[image]

Comment: This query suffers from something referred to as "RBAR" programming, or row by agonizing row. for each row in your data set, it is requerying the tblData table, and it drastically slows down the query, especially since it is wrapped in a function. Familiarize yourself with CTEs, and derived tables to break out the data you need in a set based manner and factor out the function and associated correlated subquery into other constructs.

Comment: As Jeremy suggested, using CTE to replace the use of function will work. Your function is not cheap if it has to be executed 10000 times each time you run the query. Another way that can keep the use of this function shared to other situations (where all events are listed) is to write another copy of it as a table-valued function (cut the event id param). After doing this, join the table-valued function in main query by event id. In this way, the function will be called once only for each main query.

Comment: Your query seems to expect BSP values between 1 and 3, but you're passing a BSP range or 34-55 to your stored proc: `(dbo.FN_SumWinnerRunners(td.EVENT_ID,34,55,0,7,12)` - is a BSP value typically 3 or 34?

Comment: I thought about doing it with CTE, but the thing is that I need one column for BSP between 1 and 3, one column for BSP between 3 and 5, one column for bsp between 5 and 8 (and up to a 1000) I know this is awful but is the requirement, I also need some other combinations such as other columns like BSP that will have ranges like these

Comment: if you know all your thresholds, excel string concatenation is great for generating Sum Case When statements. put all the thresholds in column a and b, then in another column create a formula to create the string you want, then copy paste into the query editor. this way if there are minor tweaks, then you can change the formula a bit, and have the change cascade through your statements. its hacky, but it works and saves typing. another option is to put all the thresholds in another table, and dynamically generate sql. see http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html for detailed information

Comment: Hello @Jeremy yes, this part is not a problem but I have just ran into a problem that I can't seem to solve with a case, I need to use this logic:

  SELECT SUM(CASE
                            WHEN(td.BSP >= BSPFrom
                                 AND td.BSP < BSPTo)
                                AND td.WIN_LOSE = Win_Lose
                            THEN td.BSP
                        END)
             FROM tblData td
             WHERE td.EVENT_ID = event_id
             HAVING COUNT(td.EVENT_NAME) > 6
                    AND COUNT(td.EVENT_NAME) <= 11

in a case, how?

Comment: I'm referring to the logic in the function, how can I put in a case a condition with a count()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove the distinct as it is redundant when you group by that column.

If the event count between 6 and 11 is pretty static, you can join the table to itself using a derived table. Then, if there is a record there, then its between 6 and 11. The query is untested, but the concept should be clear. Joining on derived tables to get additional information is a very powerful way to factor out things that are difficult to calculate in one statement in a set based manner.

```
SELECT td.EVENT_ID, 
       td.MENU_HINT, 
       td.EVENT_NAME, 
       td.EVENT_DT AS Expr1003, 
       COUNT(td.EVENT_NAME) AS [Total Runners], 
       -- AS [WinnerPrice], 
       -- COUNT(td.ID) AS [WinnerCount],
       SUM(CASE WHEN td.BSP >= 1 AND td.BSP < 2 THEN td.BSP END) AS Sum1to2, 
       count(CASE WHEN td.BSP >= 1 AND td.BSP < 2 THEN td.BSP END) AS count1to2, 
       avg(CASE WHEN td.BSP >= 1 AND td.BSP < 2 THEN td.BSP END) AS average1to2,
       dbo.FN_SumWinnerRunners(td.EVENT_ID,34,55,0,7,12) AS [TEST FUNCTION],
       SUM(CASE WHEN (td.BSP >= 2 AND td.BSP < 3) AND td.WIN_LOSE =1 THEN td.BSP END) AS SumWinnerPrice2to3, 
       count(CASE WHEN (td.BSP >= 2 AND td.BSP < 3) AND td.WIN_LOSE =1 THEN td.BSP END) AS CountWinnerPrice2to3

       SUM(CASE
                        WHEN(td.BSP >= 1
                             AND td.BSP < 3)
                            AND td.WIN_LOSE = 1
                            AND tblCount.EventCount > 6 and tblCount.EventCount <= 1
                        THEN td.BSP
                        ELSE NULL
                    END)
       FROM tblData td 
       LEFT JOIN(
          Select EventID, COUNT(*) as EventCount
          FROM tblData
          GROUP BY Event ID

          ) as tblCount ON tblData.EventID = tblCount.EventID
GROUP BY td.EVENT_ID, 
         td.MENU_HINT, 
         td.EVENT_NAME, 
         td.EVENT_DT
ORDER BY [Total Runners] DESC;
```

Comment: uhm, is not actually, and the big issue is that I have around 800 columns like this, with different combinations of bsp ranges, event count, etc

Comment: @Baldie47 so switch it up a bit. Including the count in the derived table allows you to reference the count in the case statements in the main query. then my comment on excel or dynamically driven range statements can apply here as well. I modified the answer to show getting the count per event as well.

Comment: this worked great, and using this as base, actually I made a base query with CTE (having the counts and other calculated) and just refer to it from second query.

Comment: @Baldie47 glad this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your function, but make it return table with 1 row, this will keep parallelism in your sql.
(Functions, returning tables don’t kill parallelism in sql server)

```
Create function dbo.FN_SumWinnerRunners(...)
Returns table as
Return 
(
 Select sum(...) as result from ...
);
```

Call it in your sql with `outer apply`

```
Select 
 td.event_id
,swr.result
From tblData td 
Outer apply dbo.FN_SumWinnerRunners(...) swr
```

Comment: I just tried this, good tip on the parallelism on table functions, however it is still 91% cost over 9% when comparing. https://i.imgur.com/DQXRHd6.png  and I need to do this A LOT. is there any way I can have it in a way that I'm able to pass different parameters for different columns? as putting it in outer apply asks me to pass values for all parameters, and then just call the result in the select (I want to know if I can pass paarameters in the select)

Comment: Can you provide an example? Outer apply - is the same as calling scalar function is select, it is just written in another position after “From”, but it is also called for each row, so you can pass same parameters there as in your function in your question.